# How to get rid of MS WORD add-in

Tags: c#, ms-word, add-in

In [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc442946.aspx) I read:

```
When you finish developing a project, remove the add-in assembly, 
registry entries, and security settings from your development computer. 
Otherwise, the add-in will continue to run every time that you open Word 
on your development computer.

To clean up the completed project on your development computer

In Visual Studio, on the Build menu, click Clean Solution.
```

However the continuous appearance of the add-in is really not what I need. (Yes, I can clean the solution on my pc, but once I send my application to testers, they won't have any way to get rid of it). I want the add-in to appear only when I run:

```
process.Start(filename); // where filename is something like C:\somedir\boo.docx
```

and on process.Exited event I want the add-in to be removed from the system until next time I do process.Start(filename);

**Is it possible to manage (from C# side) when the add-in appears/disappears? (OR gets installed/uninstalled)**

Comment: Such schemes are brittle because they still require manual cleanup when your addin crashes Word or the machine loses power.  It is very easy to do from Word, just document the steps in the test script.